# STM32CubeMX not showing the resolution in ADC

Tags: adc, stm32, stm32cubemx, resolution

I am trying to use ADC in stm32f103 micro-controller. I use STM32CubeMX to configure the ADC. Based on the videos I gave seen on YouTube, I must be able to configure the resolution of the ADC (8, 12 or 16 bits) in STM32CubeMX but I can't Here is what STM32CubeMX let me to configure:

[image: ADC configuration in STM32CubeMX]

I use STM32CubeMX 5.10, However when I tried with 4.27 still didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADC resolution is not configurable on the STM32F103. It's always 12 bits.

<sub>The reference manual would be a better source of information than youtube videos.</sub>